# Obtener datos del trimestre y 10 dias mas

Tags: mysql

Necesito poder obterner la informacion de una tabla mysql correspondiente a un trimestre y los 10 dias inmediatamente siguentes.
Ejemplo ,datos del primer trimestre del año= enero+febrero+marzo+10 primeros dias de abril.

Estoy usaando la funcion quarter de mysql:

```
select * from  tabla where quarter(fecha)=1
```

con eso tengo los datos del trimestre, pero como incluyo los otros 10 dias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y si agregas al query

```
or (fecha BETWEEN '2017-04-01 00:00:00' AND '20107-04-10 23:59:59')
```

Tene en cuenta que si no sabes que cuarto estas buscando, y lo pasas como parametro, vas a tener que pasar como parametro el mes tambien.

Tambien podrias usar las funciones day, month y year para construir un query un poco mas complejo pero con la misma funcionalidad.